# Javascript event listener sometimes works sometimes doesn´t

Tags: javascript, php

I have a big issue because I have an event listener that sometimes works and other does not
and I really do not know what is going on, hope someone can help me understand what is going on.

here is the code for my php form

```
<div class="master">
    <form class="login" id="login" method="post">
        <br>
        <span class="titulo"><?php echo LOGIN_TITLE ?></span>

        <div class="loginform">
            <br>
            <i class="icon"><?php echo EMAIL_IMG ?></i>
            <input type="email" class="formcontrol" id="loginMail" name="loginMail" placeholder="correo electrónico">
            <br><br>
        </div>

        <div class="loginform">
            <br>
            <i class="icon"><?php echo PASS_IMG ?></i>
            <input type="password" class="formcontrol" id="loginPass" name="loginPass" placeholder="contraseña">
            <br><br><br>
        </div>

        <div class="campo enviar">
            <input type="hidden" id="tipoAccion" value="login">
            <input type="submit" class="loginButton" value="accesar">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

---

here is my JS file

```
loginListeners(); 

// detecta los eventos en la pagina
function loginListeners() {
    document.querySelector('[value="login"]').addEventListener('submit', validarRegistro);

    
    console.log(document.querySelector('[value="login"]'));
}

function validarRegistro(event) { 
    // prevenimos que no se envie la forma hasta que lo necesitemos
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log('INSIDE THE FUNCTION');
}
```

As I said before sometimes works, and I really do not have what is going on
I after the submit button is pressed the js listener take that submit but never executes the function "validarRegistro"

I really appreciate any help

This is the result I got in js console of my browser

[image: JS CONSOLE]

---

---

> NOTE: I updated the code to show only the necessary

---

Comment: Please reduce your code down to the essentials? Take a look at making a [mcve].

Comment: If you are generating HTML content through JS you need to listen for when the document has loaded to act upon that content. https://flaviocopes.com/dom-ready/

Comment: Are you certain that the HTML is loaded before you call loginListeners or is the JS file loaded before the HTML?

Comment: @AHaworth yes, i am sure the html is loaded before.

Comment: Why don't you make a snippet with your code? It could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding the submit event to a hidden input not the form.

```
document.querySelector('[value="login"]').  <-- value="login"
```

Your form has a class and an id with login, not a value.

```
document.querySelector('#login').addEventListener('submit', validarRegistro);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, now is working great. i really appreciate it.